# C# Installer Custom Action - Graphics not Compatible with Windows 7

Tags: c#, winforms, deployment, windows-7, installation

I've written a C# Windows Form Application, and a Deployment Project for it. The Deployment Project has a Custom Action.

I wrote the Application on a Windows XP machine. When I tested it on a Windows 7 machine, I noticed that major parts of the UI were "blacked out". I discovered that this could be fixed by coding the application to "force classic UI mode" regardless of what operating system it ran on. I did this by making the contents of Main() in the already-existing program.cs read as follows:

```
static void Main()
{      
    //Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new MainForm());
}
```

That solves the problem for the main form. (Also, the Deployment Project displays correctly on Windows 7 with no similar modifications to that portion of the code.)

There is one exception: I had to write a Custom Action for the Installer which displays a Form. (The user interacts with and hits "Next" just like it was part of the original Installer.)

My problem is that there is no Main() or Program.cs in the Deployment Project or in the Custom Action (which you create as a separate Class in the same project). Consequently I don't know where I'd place the lines to "tell" the Custom Action to render in a fully-compatible display mode. The Application namespace (which contains the method I need to use) isn't available in my Custom Action at all.

I'd appreciate any pointers -- I'm sure it's an easy fix but I can't find it!

Thanks,
rs

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your custom action uses Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls version 6.0:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289524(VS.71).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773175(VS.85).aspx